# SQL Query to get the following output

Tags: sql

Select * from table1

```
col1   col2

AAAA    CE      
BBB     MK     
All     OUT
All     IN
KKK     BA
CCC     NA
KKK     IN
```

I need output as below:

```
AAAA : CE
BBB : MK
All : OUT,IN
KKK : BA, IN
CCC : NA
```

Comment: which is rdbms you are using?you have to specify here to get answer

Comment: So, what have you tried yourself?

Answer (score 2):

If this is MySQL, you can use GROUP_CONCAT function